# Tetrahedron Division

Tags: c++, algorithm, math

> Given a regular tetrahedron. All the edges were divided into N equal segments. How many non-degenerate (|volume|>0) tetrahedrons with vertices at the points of division can be built inside this tetrahedron? Vertex of given tetrahedron can't be the point of division.

Examples:

- For N=2, answer is 12.
- For N=37, answer is 65561472.

[Here is the answer with some pseudo-code](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/306272/how-many-tetrahedrons-in-a-tetrahedron/306493#306493), but I fail to translate the final step to C++. This is what I have done so far:

```
typedef unsigned long long ulong;
ulong histogram[3002];

int main() {
    memset(&histogram[0],0,sizeof(ulong)*3002);
    ulong N;
    cin >> N;
    ulong m = N-1;
    ulong u,U,z,Z;
    ulong tetra = 3*m*m*(53*m*m-34*m+1)/4;

    for( u = 1; u < N; u++) {
        U = u/(N-u);
        for( z = 1; z < N; z++) {
            Z = z/(N-z);
            histogram[U*Z]++;
        }
    }

    // How to write the following steps in C++?
    /*number_degen = 0;
    foreach fraction in histogram {
        number_degen += histogram{fraction}^2;
    }*/
    // I am trying something like this
    ulong number_degen = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i<3002; i++)
        number_degen += histogram[i] * histogram[i];


    cout<<number_degen<<endl;
    cout<<tetra-3*number_degen<<endl;
}
```

"number_degen" = "950404" if N=37,when it must be 4836

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! At which particular point do you have problems to implement this formula? Users on Stack Overflow will not provide you full solutions unless you tell us what you already tried to do.

Comment: Can you write *any* of it in C++?

Comment: Uhm, the answer you have linked to translates nearly 1:1 into C++. Where is the problem?

Comment: "typedef unsigned long long  ulong;
ulong histogram[3002];
int main()
{
    memset(&histogram[0],0,sizeof(ulong)*3002);
    
    ulong N;
    cin>>N;
    
    ulong m = N-1;
    ulong u,U,z,Z;
    ulong tetra = 3*m*m*(53*m*m-34*m+1)/4;

    for( u = 1; u < N; u++)
    {
        U = u/(N-u);
        for( z = 1; z < N; z++){
            Z = z/(N-z);
            histogram[U*Z]++;
        }
    }
"

problem is here

"number_degen = 0;
foreach fraction in histogram {
    number_degen += histogram{fraction}^2;
}"

i dont understand what's going on)

Comment: And if you post code in comments few SOers will try to understand what is going on.  Edit the code into your question.

Comment: I added the code to your question. You should always provide enough information so other users can solve your *particular* problem. As I said before, users will not solve whole tasks and such questions are likely to be closed as well as downvoted.

Comment: Do you really not know how to write `number_degen = 0;` in C++?

Comment: @Jack Why 3002 elements?

Comment: @interjay I added this comment in his code. It refers to the whole last block (I think he doesn't know how to take the square in particular.)

Answer (score 2):

One problem (it might be the only thing missing in your implementation) is how you take the square in C++ (and many other languages):

```
number_degen += histogram[fraction] ^ 2;    // <-- wrong!
```

The `^` operator in C++ will *not* evaluate the power of two numbers, but their bitwise XOR combination. To take the square of two numbers, you have two possibilities: Either multiply the number with itself or take it to the power of two. For integer numbers, the first should be preferred, as taking the power of a number will result in a floating point number.

```
number_degen += histogram[fraction] * histogram[fraction];
```

Comment: you right, but it get "950404" if N=37,when it must be 4836

Comment: Well, then there is something different wrong. Couple of things I can't figure out in your implementation: Why do you use exactly `3002` elements? Where do you put the formula `tetra` and the `number_degen` together into the result? The formula on your linked answer seems to require to add them together.

Comment: In this task N∈[2..3000]. Well, tetra is all possible tetrahedrons. At last it must looks like "tetra-3*number_degen", and it must get 65561472. I dont write it at first, because my code get bad "number_degen" and it is main problem